# Is there a way to add comments through Google Photo API?

Tags: api, google-photos, google-photos-api

I would like to know if I can add comments to a google photo shared album via the API?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

The 1.0 version of the API seems limited with respect to modifying anything. You can't even add a photo to an album except by specifying an albumId at upload time.

The one exception is Album 'enrichments' see https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/albums/addEnrichment
These do allow you to add text to the album overview. Not quite the same thing as user comments - and would only work for the album owner I believe.